# how to activate ports using springboot and docker?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, port

So for one of my university assignments we've been tasking with creating a CRUD api using a framework of our choice, i went with spring boot, as an additional requirement it must also be in a container using docker.
To pass the module the server must pass a series of tests, they all fail due to a port 8000 not being active, these ports have been set in the application.Properties file and if i navigate to http://localhost:8000/ or use curl commands it all functions as it should (post get delete ect.)
Is it an issue on my end or with the tests? see image for test output.[pytest output log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93bAp.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did your instructor mention which ports you should use? If the tests are going to run on a server that you don't control you may need this information. I'm curious how you chose Port 8000 as this would be rather uncommon. Have you tried setting the Port to 8080 in your application.properties? 8080 is the common port to use for HTTP traffic.

As an alternative, you may need to port forward in Docker and ensure that your container is listening on Port 8000 if you have to use that port. There are steps to configure port forwarding when creating your Docker container.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response to further clarify the ports my instructor specified is 8000, this port is also present in my application.properties file. Asking here was my last port of call before pulling him up on the situation, apologies if what im asking is not clear i do struggle with explaining things to others. if there are any other details that may assist you please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are still facing the issue but a couple questions: 
1. When you say it worked with localhost:8080 are you running your app inside a docker container locally? Or are you just running your Spring Boot app and hitting the url outside of the container?
2. It's odd that in your logs you are getting an error with the application trying to reach out to http://server:8080. This tells me that something is likely misconfigured inside the container or in your application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand is you are trying to run your spring boot application after containerising it using docker. If that is the case then at the time of specifying docker run command you can add port parameter.
In your case it will be:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 img_name
```

let me know if the scenario is something different